# Debugging Subprocesses in PyDev

Tags: python, pydev

We are trying to debug C++ code called by a Python script (using subprocess.call). Is there a way to do this with PyDev? I am a Java developer and we are developing an Eclipse RCP application, and can write custom code as needed to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug c++ code, you need a c++ debugger (and PyDev won't really help you there).

My suggestion is looking for a c++ debugger in this case (you can use gdb in windows and linux -- on windows you can also use visual c++ if you want -- you should be able to attach to a running process on both cases -- I think that CDT also has some gdb integration which you can use if you set it up properly).